# Variables no cambia, ¿Por qué?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Buenos dias,tengo un error en este código y no sé cual es llevo días intendado solucionar pero no se encontrarlo. Cuando lo ejecuto en la función aprender `w1` y `w2` tendría que cambiar de valor, al igual que `v` pero ninguno de ellos lo hace y no sé como solucionarlo.

gracias

```js
var n1 = [6,3,9,8,6,5,3,4,2,1,6,7,8,5,2,4,6,1,5];
var n2 = [5,6,1,8,5,3,2,3,5,7,8,3,2,1,4,6,1,2,3];
var nf = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0];
var res;
var s;
var w1 =   Math.random().toFixed(2);
var w2 =  Math.random().toFixed(2);
var v;
console.log(w1+" |-| "+w2);


function aprender(n1,n2,nf,w1,w2){
  res = (n1 * w1) + (n2 * w2);
  res = res / 10;
  s = Math.round(res);
  console.log(nf+" |-| "+ res)
  //console.log(res +" |-| "+s)

  if(res < nf){
    w1 = w1 * 0.2
    w2 = w2 * 0.2
    v++
  }

  if(res > nf){
    w1 = w1 * -0.2
    w2 = w2 * -0.2
    v++
  }
  console.log(">"+w1+ " |-| "+ w2)
}


for(var i = 0; i < n1.length; i++){
  aprender(n1[i],n2[i], nf[i], w1, w2);
}
aprender(8,5,1,w1,w1);


console.log(res +" |-| "+s)
console.log(w1+" |-| "+w2+ " |-| "+v);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico con lo que esperas? No sé si estoy entendiendo la lógica. El código realiza operaciones, y 'v' no es un número (NaN) porque no lo inicializas, deberías igualarlo a 0 al inicio de la función para que incremente el valor y lo puedas usar como contador. Y después del bucle ejecutas la función con unos valores fijos que van a dar siempre el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 5):

### `w1` y `w2`

```
function aprender(n1,n2,nf,w1,w2){
```

Estas declarando de nuevo `w1` y `w2` como parámetros.

Estos parámetros **son unas variables nuevas**, no comparten la memoria/datos con `w1` y `w2` globales, y **ocultan la referencia a estas variables**.

Como variables locales que son, una vez que la llamada a la función acaba las variables salen de *scope* y desaparecen.

Es mucho más sencillo simplemente no pasar los parámetros, de forma que no se oculten las variables globales.

En cualquier caso, si tienes una variable local que oculta una global, puedes acceder a la global a través de su entorno. Si estamos hablando de una página web, sería `window`

```
window.w1 = w1; // actualiza la variable global tomando el valor de la variable local
```

---

### `v`

`v` es un caso distinto. Nunca le asignas un valor inicial, así que empieza por ser `undefined`, que no es lo mismo que `0`. Cuando le sumas `1`, se convierte a `NaN` (*Not a Number*, "Esto no es un número", que es un valor que indica un error), y sigue así cada vez que le sumas 1. La solución es inicialiizar el valor a `0`

```js
var n1 = [6,3,9,8,6,5,3,4,2,1,6,7,8,5,2,4,6,1,5];
var n2 = [5,6,1,8,5,3,2,3,5,7,8,3,2,1,4,6,1,2,3];
var nf = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0];
var res;
var s;
var w1 =   Math.random().toFixed(2);
var w2 =  Math.random().toFixed(2);
var v = 0;
console.log(w1+" |-| "+w2);


function aprender(n1,n2,nf){
  res = (n1 * w1) + (n2 * w2);
  res = res / 10;
  s = Math.round(res);
  console.log(nf+" |-| "+ res)
  //console.log(res +" |-| "+s)

  if(res < nf){
    w1 = w1 * 0.2;
    w2 = w2 * 0.2;
    v++;
  }

  if(res > nf){
    w1 = w1 * -0.2;
    w2 = w2 * -0.2;
    v++;
  }
  console.log(">"+w1+ " |-| "+ w2);
}


for(var i = 0; i < n1.length; i++){
  aprender(n1[i],n2[i], nf[i]);
}
aprender(8,5,1);


console.log(res +" |-| "+s);
console.log(w1+" |-| "+w2+ " |-| "+v);
```